# Redux function "connect" assigns wrong state value in statless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-props

I'm trying to pass some prop to a stateless component for my conditionally rendering needs. When assigning redux state value to my variable in `connect()` like `var: state.reducer.var` I don't get "state.reducer.var" object. Instead I get the whole state object.

When `console.log(state.reducer.var)` in connect() as a callback, I get my expected result - var value. Tho, when `console.log(var)` as a callback passing my freshly assigned var to it, I get an object that I'd get when `console.log(state)`.

In my child component I get `undefined` using my var as `props.var`

```
const _ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }, props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {!props.isAuthed
        ? <Redirect to="auth" noThrow />
        : <Component {...rest} />
      }
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const ProtectedRoute = connect(
  (state) => ({
    isAuthed: state.user.isAuthed,
  }, (isAuthed) => {console.log('state value: ', isAuthed)})
)(_ProtectedRoute);
```

I expect my var that I assigned redux state to be passed down to my stateless `_ProtectedRoute` component as a prop so I can use it in a conditional statement.

Comment: the second argument to `connect` is not a callback; it's an object (or a function returning an object) containing a map of prop names to Redux action-creator functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My lack of knowledge about functions arguments was the problem.
My `connect()` function was indeed functional (should've worked). There was a problem with taking in props in my child component.
`({ component: Component, ...rest })` is already "The props". `({ component: Component, ...rest }, props)` means that I assign another "props" argument which is undefined.
So, instead of converting `component` to `Component` to use as a `<Component />` in my function later, it should've been done later before `return()`. It leads to passing props as an argument as usual. So, my child component can now receive redux state as props from `mapStateToProps()`.

P.S. As a few people mention, console-loging in `connect()` is indeed wrong as it is not a callback.

```
const _ProtectedRoute = props => {
  const Component = props.component;
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {!props.isAuthed
        ? <Redirect to="auth" noThrow />
        : <Component {...props} />
      }
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthed: state.user.isAuthed
});

const ProtectedRoute = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(_ProtectedRoute);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right and it should work as expected but I did notice a syntax problem in your code, there should be a closing parentheses after curly braces in first argument to connect, also second argument should return an object, something like below

```
const ProtectedRoute = connect(
  (state) => ({
    isAuthed: state.user.isAuthed,
  }), (dispatch) => ({
      printAuth:(isAuthed) => {console.log('state value: ', isAuthed)}
  })
)(_ProtectedRoute);
```